# Laravel Eloquent - Change with('relation') dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

### Database Tables

Please try to understand the database tables here. It's kinda like a polymorphic relationship. But what's different here is that the folder table, in this case, is not a child of files tables instead it's the other way around.

folder

| id | model_id | model_type | name | etc.. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | App\Models\FileA | a folder name | etc.. |
| 1 | 1 | App\Models\FileB | a folder name | etc.. |

file_a

| id | name | etc.. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | file a name | etc.. |
| 2 | file a name 2 | etc.. |

file_b

| id | name | etc.. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | file b name | etc.. |

So, my question is **how do I fetch the list of all folders and the number of files it contains** using laravel eloquent?

if my question doesn't make sense, please ask questions on the comment?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Attempt:

Folder Model

```
public function file()
{
    return $this->morphTo('file', 'file_type', 'id', 'folder_id');
}

public static function foldersWithFilesCount()
{
    return self::with(['file' => function ($query) {
        return $query->count();
    }])->where('brand_id', 6)->paginate(10);
}
```

Comment: Come on, give us an attempt at least!

Comment: @JustCarty Added what I tried. Let me know if it makes sense

Comment: In your example folder does not have a unique id

Comment: That's just a typo @IGP

Comment: Can you edit your question with the result you'd like to obtain? An example object I mean.